# change strings: xelatex to pdflatex

Tags: xetex, pdftex, templates, strings

Could you help me? I used this template for my CV in the past:

https://www.latextemplates.com/template/plasmati-graduate-cv

It uses Xelatex to run (I don't know why, but that's it)

Now I need to update the file, but for some reason XeLatex doesn't work...
Could you please tell me how to change the strings so to make it work using PdfLatex (so that the problem will be fixed forever)

Thank you

Comment: this question isn't really clear enough to answer:  what error message do you get, what do you mean by "string" why can't you use xelatex?

Comment: if you open the document on the link, you can see how the opening is structured. I guess that it's in the opening that one defines that the document must be compiled in Xelatex (some strings probably belong only to Xelatex grammar?). I'm asking what to change in the opening, so that the document becomes a simple PdfLatex

Comment: Well, it uses fontspec, xltxtra and xunicode. That is very xelatexy. But can't you just search for a well-written (good style) template?

Comment: sorry that isn't a question. Firstly your question should not require following external links (I actually followed the first link but that just leads to a web page not tex code) but more importantly why pick a xelatex template and assume that it can be used with pdflatex, certainly the fonts will typically not be available at all.

Comment: This clearly is a XY question. What you should investigate is why it doesn't work with XeLaTeX anymore. On the other and, ***never ever*** assume a template works.

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted leads to a document with some XeLaTeX-specific things:

- the packages `fontspec`, `xltxtra` and `xunicode`
- macros like `\setmainfont`, `\defaultfontfeatures` (and essentially `\fb` as it is font adoption you do not need without other font)

However, if you remove those you will not have the fonts of Fontin family.